# Profile Pics not showing with Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook

I am using [Facebook Connect](http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php) and showing the users Facebook profile pic on the website, but for some reason (or is deliberate) the profile picture won't show unless i have logged in with Facebook Connect, if i just browse the site normally i just see the default silhouette, but if i log in with Facebook Connect they appear correct....

PS If it helps i have noticed this website seems to have it working, you can see in the code they are using the fb:profile-pic tag and the pics still show even when you are not logged in - http://www.ratemyarea.com/people/mike-1

Comment: it's something I encountered months ago and I gave up working on it.

Comment: yeah i am getting that feeling here but it is kind of vital to the project, surely there must be a way around it ?

Comment: Post a link to your site? I've implemented FBC a few times with no logins.

Comment: i can't post to it at the moment as it is still in development on my machine, but if you could try to explain or point me in the right direction that was be brill - everything is working brill expect i can't get profile pics to appear unless the user is logged in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not use IsConnected(), and only pic_square can be used when not connected

Comment: can you give more explanations please. I don't get it. Thanks.

Comment: This answer does not meet SO standards.